# comparing float64 dtype over boolean condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Can someone pls check below code & suggest the changes required. I want to compare float64 dtype over a bool in If statement.

```
if (df1['A'].max() > pd.to_numeric(df2['X']) | (df1['A'].max()-df1['A'].mean())/ df1['A'].mean()):
print(.........)
```

**Compilation error -**
*TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]*

Comment: You can't compare an array with a scalar value `df1['A'].max() > pd.to_numeric(df2['X'])` what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @EdChum, df1['A'].max() returns a single value hence am able to compare. Issue is with using OR for evaluating another condition.

Comment: Again I ask you to explain your logic completely, you'd comparing a scalar with an array on the left hand side, and then or-ing this with something that will produce a scalar and then trying to `if` all of this, the presence of the array will produce a boolean array which `if` will not handle